# no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsTextItem::QGraphicsTextItem(int, myClass*)' ^

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

Здравствуйте, такая проблема:

```cpp
/home/u0807/QtApplication_2/main.cpp:83: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsTextItem::QGraphicsTextItem(int, myClass*)'
 itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(0, this);
                                            ^
```

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QString>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

.....
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    item[i] = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, this);
    item[i]->setRect(QRectF(-90, -35 + (i * 16), 15, 15));
    item[i]->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    item[i]->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    item[i]->setToolTip("10.31." + QString::number(i + 3) + ".130");
}
itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(0, this);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрите какие у класса `QGraphicsTextItem` есть конструкторы и сравните с вашим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    item[i] = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0);
    item[i]->setRect(QRectF(-90, -35 + (i * 16), 15, 15));
    item[i]->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    item[i]->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    item[i]->setToolTip("10.31." + QString::number(i + 3) + ".130");

    myClass::addItem(item[i]);
}
itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(0);
myClass::addItem(itemText[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Компилятор вам сообщает, что классе `QGraphicsTextItem` нет конструктора вида `QGraphicsTextItem(int, myClass*)`, либо он не может неявно привести переданные параметры к аргументам какого-либо из имеющихся вариантов конструкторов.

Comment: Главный прикол в том, что я эту программку писал в NetBeans, и там всё скомпилилось нормально, а теперь пытаюсь скомпилить в QtCreator.

Comment: @fredwriter Ошибки вам выдает не среда разработки, а компилятор. Поэтому смотрите чем компиляторы отличаюся.

Comment: @fredwriter Скорее всего это вы где ошиблись, так как первым параметром в подходящем конструкторе `QGraphicsTextItem` должна быть `QString`, и я не верю что в природе найдется хоть один компилятор Си++ который неявно преобразует целое в `QString`.

Comment: У меня был компилятор g++, и сейчас g++. На NetBeans я писал давно уже эту программку.

Comment: `itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(0, this);`
`itemText[1]->setPlainText(Ss[0][4]);` Сначала мы создаем, а потом инициализируем SetPlainTex

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(QString::number(0), this);
```

Если вам нужен именно ноль там, либо просто

```
itemText[1] = new QGraphicsTextItem(this);
```

У данного класса в документации (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#QGraphicsTextItem-1) есть два конструктора, один из них перед родителем принимает строку, а второй принимает только указатель на родителя.

Comment: я и уже пробовал так, у меня дело именно в this, контекст не тот. У меня она выполняется в контексте реализации слота для класса `myClass` описан так: `class myClass : public QGraphicsScene {
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
        myClass(QObject *parent = 0);
        QTimer *timer;
        InputDialog* pInputDialog = NULL;
        QDialog* D = NULL;
        QGraphicsEllipseItem* item[4];

public slots:
  void timer_overflow();
  void btnClicked_Add();
  void btnClicked_Del();
  void slotFinished();
private:

};`

Comment: То есть класс myClass у меня типа QGraphicsScene, а нужен по идее QGraphicsItem. Но родителем же должна являться сцена. Не могу понять, этот самый код у меня работал в NetBeans.

Comment: Тяжело сказать, какое именно поведение вам нужно от данного участка кода и класса в целом, но если MyClass унаследовать также и от QGraphicsItem, то данный код компилируется.  Но мне кажется, это не лучшее решение. Возможно проблема в архитектуре участка проекта.

Comment: QGraphicsItem является базовым классом для элементов сцены, но самасцена не может быть родителем элементов, она их только в себе размещает. Логично было бы создать в методе новый итем и добавить его к this методом addItem, опять-таки, зависит от требуемого поведения